# how are elements assigned to clusters in foreach() when doing parallel computing in R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I have a set of elements to run by user-defined function in R. It takes long time to run for these elements sequentially. Then I switch to parallel computing using `foreach()`, `%dopar%`, `makecluster()`, and `registerdoparallel()`. I am wondering how are these elements distributed to clusters. Say I have 100 elements and register 5 clusters, Element 1~20 are assigned to cluster 1, and so on so forth, or they are assigned randomly. Thanks

Comment: You can trace what is happening by reading the function code if you really want to see how it works. For instance typing the following into your console `parallel::splitIndices` WITHOUT () will show you that this method splits them from start to finish iff there are more than a certain number of tasks. So for 4 clusters you'd run 1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20....except it looks like the minimum is 1,000 so you'd run all the actions on one cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ready, first served:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(3))

foreach(i = 1:20, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  Sys.getpid()
}
[1] 13004  5924  6600 13004  5924 13004  6600  5924 13004  5924 13004  5924 13004
[14]  5924  6600 13004  5924  6600 13004  5924

stopCluster(cl)
```